# AndroidX itemTouchListener

Tags: androidx

I have just migrated a project to androidX and have managed to fix all teh issues except 1. which is the implimentation of the touch listener below.

```
private fun setItemTouchListner() {
    val touchListner = object: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView?, viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, target: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, direction: Int) {
            var rec: ChargeRecord? = null
            if (viewHolder != null) {
                rec = mAdapter?.getRecord((viewHolder.adapterPosition))
            }


            // delete record from cloud

            if (rec != null) {
                firebase?.child(rec.id)?.removeValue()
                recordsViewModel?.deleteRecord(rec)
            }

            // remove record from list
            if (viewHolder != null) {
                records_list.adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
            }
        }

    }
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(touchListner)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(records_list)
}
```

I get an object is not abstract error and override does nothing error. I have searched around and tried to reformat the code but cant seem to fix it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh
After alot of looking and pondering i finally worked out, i had to re-impliment the move and swipe methods.

this fixed the issue

cheers